# Auth0Client.LoginAsync() v4.x doesn't return refresh token in a C# WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, access-token, auth0

Here's my code:

```
 var auth0 = new Auth0Client(
     Properties.Settings.Default.auth0Domain,
     Properties.Settings.Default.auth0ClientID);
 var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
 var windowWrapper = new WindowWrapper(handle);

 var user = await auth0.LoginAsync(
     owner: windowWrapper, 
     scope: "openid profile", 
     withRefreshToken: true);
```

The return value contains a null refresh token. I also tried setting the device parameter to an arbitrary value, but that didn't help. I recently switched from Auth0 v3.x to v4.x. Auth0 v3.x returned a refresh token. Did this break in v4.x? If not, what do I need to do to get a refresh token?

Comment: After a few weeks of communications with the Auth0 support team, I got something to work. From what I've inferred, they're in the middle of switching to a new version of their API that is incompatible with the previous version. I was using the latest stable version of the Auth0.WinformsOrWPF library, which does not work anymore. The version that works is in beta. It's called Auth0.Oidcclient.WPF. They provide sample code [here](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-WinFormsWPF-oidc-samples).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of identity providers are you using? - I tried this with Microsoft Live, and a Google account and that worked.

When you Login/Authenticate, do you get any other fields filled in the "user" result (without giving away any details/tokens).

Can you try like this i.e. not use "profile" in the scope.

```
 var user = await auth0.LoginAsync(
     owner: windowWrapper, 
     scope: "openid offline_access", 
     withRefreshToken: true,
     device: "my-device");
```

or

```
 var user = await auth0.LoginAsync(
     owner: windowWrapper, 
     scope: "openid", 
     withRefreshToken: true,
     device: "my-device");
```

Internally it appends `"offline_access"` onto the scope name if you have `withRefreshToken=true` that's why either of the above works.

You also need to supply an "id" individually for each of your devices so they can each be assigned their own refresh token.

When a refresh token has been issued, it will show up in the `Dashboard` -> in `Users` -> choose the User Authentication identity used to login -> then in `User Details` -> choose the `Devices` tab ... this will show how many `Number of Refresh Tokens` have been issued to your device.

[image]

As mentioned in the documentation, you shouldn't keep requesting a refresh_token....only do that when they've expired - (see how I requested more than I needed) - perhaps you hit the throttling limits on requesting refresh tokens...and it simply returns a "null" token instead...but still let your authentication succeed without error....a possibility?

Here's the documentation on refresh token (you probably know this already as you must have used it in v3).

- https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token#revoke-a-refresh-token-in-the-dashboard

Comment: Thanks again, Colin! To answer your questions: 1) I tried it with Facebook and Google, 2) the user object contains a valid Auth0AccessToken, an empty IdToken, a valid IdTokenExpiresAt, a valid Profile, a null RefreshToken (of course), and a non-empty State. I tried it with and without "profile" in the scope, as well as with and without "offline_access" in the scope. I revoked the refresh tokens (thanks for the tip - I didn't know about that). Nothing worked, though. Still, this is good. I submitted a ticket to Auth0. Now I can rule out these possibilities (if they respond, anyway).